# WooCommerce checking for first-time orders

Tags: php, woocommerce

Is there a way to check at `woocommerce_payment_complete` if the order that processed was a first time order and not a renewal? I don't see anything related via the `$order` object.

I am using a function at the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook to check if the order is a first time order or renewal and then sending come data via curl method, but not sure how to go about the basic act of checking this?

Answer (score 0):

```
`function returningCustomer($billingEmail){
    // Get all customer orders
    if(get_current_user_id() != 0){
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 2, // more than 1
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with completed
            'fields'      => 'ids', // Return Ids completed
        ) );
        // return "true" when customer has already at least one order
        // (false if not)
        return count($customer_orders) > 1 ? true : false;
    }
    else {
        $customer_orders_email = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 2, // more than 1
            'meta_key'    => '_billing_email',
            'meta_value'  => $billingEmail,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with completed
            'fields'      => 'ids', // Return Ids completed
        ) );
        // return "true" when customer has already at least one order
        // (false if not)
        return count($customer_orders_email) > 1 ? true : false;
    }
}`
```

Believe this should work